# Sigma Algebras generated by two classes of subsets

Tags: measure-theory

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two collection of subsets in $\Omega$  (Sample Space), I need to prove that 
$$\sigma(A_1) \subseteq \sigma(A_2).$$  I understand that there exist minimal unique $\sigma$-algebras generated by $A_1$ & $A_2$ respectively. However, I am not sure what needs to be demonstrated mathematically, in order to prove the subset status.

I tried to construct an example for this.
Let A1={1,2} , A2={1,2,3} , Ω={1,2,3,4}

Then,

σ(A1)={∅,Ω,{1,2},{3,4}}

σ(A2)={∅,Ω,{1,2,3},{4}}

How can I proceed beyond this. I am confused as how to interpret the subsets as opposed to elements.

Appreciate your comments. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: Your slashes are the wrong one by the way. You should use the backslash.

Comment: Probably add the hypothesis $A_1\subset A_2$. After this is done, remind us how $\sigma(A)$ was introduced to you.

Comment: If by "with the equality" you mean that $\sigma(A_1)=\sigma(A_2)$ might hold, you might want to use $\subseteq$ (produced by `\subseteq`) instead of $\subset$ (produced by `\subset`). Also note that you can get subscripts in $A_1$ and $A_2$ like this: `A_1`, `A_2`.

Comment: What did means is that you need some condition in order to say something.

Comment: Please correct the question.  Do not leave us to guess what you meant to ask.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.
If $\sigma(A_1) \subseteq \sigma(A_2)$
 is true, then the opposite inclusion is also true(because you don't make any assumption on $A_1$ and $A_2$ other than they are collections of subsets of $\Omega$).
So the both are equal. This is clearly not true in general.
Your example does not make sense, either.
$A_1$ and $A_2$ should be collections of subsets of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 4):

You may forget the hypothesis $A_1\subset A_2$ or another one which is equivalent to it.

Then we know that $A_2$ is in $\sigma(A_2)$, then $A_1$ is in $\sigma(A_2)$.
Since $\sigma(A_1)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $A_1$, then $\sigma(A_1)\subset \sigma(A_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the Edit, I suggest to solve the exercise below.

**Exercise** Let $A$ and $B$ denote two subsets of a nonempty set $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal F$ denote the smallest sigma-algebra containing $A$ and $\mathcal G$  the smallest sigma-algebra containing $B$.

- Assume that $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal G$ and $\mathcal F\ne \mathcal G$. Then, either $A=\varnothing$ or $A=\Omega$.
- Assume that $\mathcal F=\mathcal G$. Then, either $A=B$ or $A=\Omega\setminus B$.

Comment: I am sorry, but it's not clear to me yet. Could you please explain further.

Comment: ?? Did you try the exercise?