# Sigma Algebra of Subsets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ denote two subsets of a non-empty set $\Omega$. Also let $\sigma(A)$ denote the smallest sigma algebra generated by $A$. Show the following:

> If $A \subseteq B$, then $\sigma(A) \subseteq \sigma(B)$.

I think a similar question was asked at this link, although I cannot follow the solution by Elhaaj:

[Sigma Algebras generated by two classes of subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196043/sigma-algebras-generated-by-two-classes-of-subsets)

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Maybe what you want is that $A$ and $B$ are collections of subsets of $\Omega$, with $A\subseteq B$? If $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$, then $\sigma(A)$ would just be $\{\emptyset,A,\Omega\setminus A,\Omega\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant $A \subset B \subset 2^{\Omega}$ as suggested by Andrés E. Caicedo in the comments.

**Hint**: Recall that $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains every set in $X$. Since $B$ contains every set in $A$, we can conclude that...

Comment: Thanks, I got it now given that we have to consider collections of subsets instead of just subsets